# Let $f(x)$ be continous in $x_0$ and $f(x_0)\ne 0$. Prove that $\exists C>0$ and neighbouhood of $x_0$ such that $|f(x)| \ge C$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-verification, continuity

> Let a function $f(x)$ be continuous in some point $x_0$ and $f(x_0) \ne 0$. Prove that there exists a number $C > 0$ and neighbourhood of $x_0$ such that forall $x$ in that neighbourhood the following inequality holds: 
>   $$
> |f(x)| \ge C
> $$

The problem statement says that $f(x_0) \ne 0$, so it is either greater than $0$ or less than $0$. Let's consider the case for $f(x_0) > 0$. In such case by continuity of $f(x)$ we know:
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0) > 0
$$

Or in other words:
$$
\forall \epsilon > 0\ \exists \delta_\epsilon > 0\ \forall x: |x-x_0| < \delta_\epsilon \implies |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon
$$

Since $f(x_0) \ne 0$ we may let $\epsilon = {f(x_0)\over 2}$. In such case:
$$
|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon \\
|f(x) - f(x_0)| < { f(x_0)\over 2 } \\
-{ f(x_0)\over 2 } < f(x) - f(x_0) < { f(x_0)\over 2 }\\
0<{f(x_0)\over 2} < f(x) < {3f(x_0)\over 2}
$$

So we may now choose any $C \in \left(0; {f(x_0)\over 2}\right)$, which would imply  $f(x) \ge C$.

Similar reasoning is applied to the case when $f(x_0) < 0$.

> I'm not sure my reasoning above is valid, so I would like to kindly ask for verification. Or for a correct proof if the above makes no sense. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, this absolutely fine ;) The neighbourhood would be $(-f(x_0)/2,f(x_0)/2)$ when $f(x_0)>0$.

Comment: This looks correct. You have $f(x) \geq C$ for all $|x-x_0|\leq\delta_\epsilon$. The reason this works is because of continuity, i.e. the statement is for all $\epsilon >0$..., the the particular choice of $\epsilon = f(x_0)/2$ works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, the above proof is valid. But for a couple suggestions in terms of proof writing, in the last line you said that $f(x_0) \geq C$, but this is only true for all $x$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta$. Just make sure you include that in your last line so that people don't think you are saying that you are proving it for every $x$.

Have you been introduced to the neighbourhood notation? It is basically $$B_r(x_0) := \{|x-x_0| < r \quad| \quad \forall x \text{ in your domain.}\}$$ This way you can say $$ |f(x) - f(x_0)|<\epsilon $$
as 
$$ B_\epsilon (x_0)$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).